# How do I input a number / time of 01:10 from my code?

Tags: javascript

I have this working code below to input a `number/tme` in textbox. This code below is functioning well but I want to set my textbox value into `00:00` and edit my `function` code like the second `jsfiddle` however my edited code is not going well as my idea. In my second jsfiddle I want to input a time of `05:30` but the code is replacing any number that input by a user from the textbox `0`

```
    function MaskedTextboxDPSDeparture() {
    var myMask = "__:__";
    var myCorrectionOut2 = document.getElementById("Departure");
    var myText = "";
    var myNumbers = [];
    var myOutPut = ""
    var theLastPos = 1;
    myText = myCorrectionOut2.value;
    //get numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(myText.charAt(i)) && myText.charAt(i) != " ") {
            myNumbers.push(myText.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    //write over mask
    for (var j = 0; j < myMask.length; j++) {
        if (myMask.charAt(j) == "_") { //replace "_" by a number 
            if (myNumbers.length == 0)
                myOutPut = myOutPut + myMask.charAt(j);
            else {
                myOutPut = myOutPut + myNumbers.shift();
                theLastPos = j + 1; //set current position
            }
        } else {
            myOutPut = myOutPut + myMask.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("Departure").value = myOutPut;
    document.getElementById("Departure").setSelectionRange(theLastPos, theLastPos);
}
document.getElementById("Departure").onkeyup = MaskedTextboxDPSDeparture;
```

HTML

```
< input id="Departure" type="text" style="width: 35px; text-align: center" value="__:__" />
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/87x28zud/)

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/87x28zud/1/)

Any suggestion will accepted. Thanks.

Comment: If you initialize the value to `00:00`, the code can't tell which characters were entered by the user and which came from the initial value.

Comment: Please write comments for negative vote.

Comment: @Barmar How do I input a time in value of `00:00` in my second jsfiddle? or How do I modify my first fiddle?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to custom code this? You tagged your question as JQuery, and there are multiple masked input plugins for JQuery, such as: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput and https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask - and if you were specifically aiming for a vanilla JS solution I would suggest either using select boxes or just letting the user put in whatever they want and validating with a regex, raising an error if it isn't a valid time.

Comment: @Mic sorry about the tagging i just following the suggested tag. I have a reason about this code to be modify because the my leader wants that the textbox is default in `00:00` and the user wont enter the `:` anymore. I try to edit it like in jsfiddle2 but i my idea was wrong.

Comment: I would probably hook in on the keyup event, and still use a regex to validate because there are plenty of ways to get invalid input in with the regex.
The basic event work would be along the lines of this: https://jsfiddle.net/87x28zud/3/
It's rough, but essentially accomplishes the same thing as your first fiddle except with about half the code. But again, I don't think this is the best solution to time input fields.

Comment: @Mic I probably edit a lot of my code if I use your method :) but can you do it like my code? I mean if I enter 10 numbers only the first 4 numbers will show?.

Comment: @Mic like to concept of my 2nd jsfiddle